# How does git recognize past versions?

Tags: git

I've been learning git for 2 weeks now and I actually have enough knowledge to use git properly, but I'm crazy curious to understand how git knows objects of previous commits.

I know that git stores blob trees and commits as their sha1 function results in the objects folder. When we change something, new data is added to objects folder and suppose we changed some file in our working directory and its sha1 hash changed completely and git has only hash from old file. How can Git give us the file we need, it hash only Sha1 hash left and it can't be decrypted backwards.

Comment: The main trick is that there is a file that uses the hash as its name.

Comment: "I know that git stores blob trees and commits as their sha1 function results in the objects folder." That's not correct. The *contents* of a file are stored as a blob; the hash is just used to *identify* the blob.

Comment: @chepner That's a little misleading to say to a beginner, because the hash is also _derived from_ the contents of the blob. (I know _you_ know that; I'm just saying we need to watch what we say to someone who knows nothing about it.)

Comment: @matt But that's basically the answer to the question: Git knows about old versions precisely because the old version never leaves the repository. (Knowing how commits form a DAG is the rest of the answer, which you and Obsidian cover already.)

Comment: I was just picking at the word "just". :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there four types of objets : blobs, commits, **trees** and anotated tags.

This means that each commit references a tree object that is supposed to reflect the index's state at commit time, which tree, in turn, refers to all the file contents stored in index at this moment.

Moreover, a commit also refers to its parent commit. These successive references to each previous commit are actually what forms history, like a huge linked list.

You may check out the content of any object using **cat-file** command. In fact, commits are just a small text fragment that contains what we just explained above. Here's an example picked from Linux's kernel repository:

```
$ git cat-file -p 7be099662200c7e
tree f500f1747be71abf174da284e020148e796958a4
parent 2c821d262c4b7201ed2460ffddc05dacb77a0313
author Jan Sokolowski <jan.sokolowski@intel.com> 1673273478 +0100
committer Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@linuxfoundation.org> 1683814296 +0900

i40e: use int for i40e_status

commit 5180ff1364bc26c031b54a68a80aa90ce0028b70 upstream.

To prepare for removal of i40e_status, change the variables
from i40e_status to int. This eases the transition when values
are changed to return standard int error codes over enum i40e_status.
…
```

So committing new stuff is just a matter of adding new objects. When you modify something that already exists (i.e. using `commit --amend`), git simply discards the related objects and create brand new ones to replace them.

What's really nice here is that those old objets aren't immediately deleted. They will be when the garbage collector pass, and only if they're both old enough and not referenced anywhere anymore.

This enables you to easily retrieve them if ever you deleted them by mistake (using `--amend` or when rushing into `reset --hard` too soon).

Answer (score 1):

> suppose we changed some file in our working directory and its sha1 hash changed completely and git has only hash from old file. How can Git give us the file we need

Git knows nothing whatever about "changed some file"; it does not traffic in changes. The phrase "its sha1 hash changed" is nonsensical; there is no "it" in the story.

Git traffics solely in commits, which are *snapshots* of the *entire* state of the project, that is, *all* the files. Those files are represented in the commit as a list of pathnames each of which is tied to a hash which in turn is the name of a file containing some stuff.

As a simple case, imagine a project where there is only one file under Git control, *myfile*. You add it and you commit (call this commit A). You change its contents and you add it and you commit (call this commit B). By definition, *myfile* has a different hash in the first commit (A) than it does in the second commit (B), because the hash of a file *is* an expression of its contents — only if *myfile* were identical in both commits would the hashes be the same (a clever trick for saving space in the repository, among other things).

But a commit also contains *pathnames* of its contents (I'm simplifying). Each pathname in a commit points to a hash which is also, by an incredible coincidence, the name (I'm simplifying) of the file where the contents are stored. Thus, when you ask Git "what happened to *myfile*", it uses the pathname *myfile* to look at the hash to look at the file contents, and then it can walk backwards to the previous commit (because commits are chained via parentage) and look at the pathname *myfile* again to look at *that* hash to look at *those* file contents:

```
commit B -> list of names -> "myfile" -> hash -> contents
   |
(parent)
   |
commit A -> list of names -> "myfile" -> hash -> contents
```

So the simple answer is: *nothing* connects the first set of file contents with the second set of file contents. But that doesn't matter because the only way you're going to query the matter is through the *commit* which also contains a list of pathnames.

If you're doing a log with patches or a diff, Git might *describe* this to you by saying "commit B changed the 10th line of *myfile* from "hello" to "bonjour"". But that is just a *deduction* that Git makes *in real time* as it presents the information to you, because it knows that *you* care about these things you call "changes". Git knows that *you* think this is the "same file". But Git doesn't think that. It just thinks in terms of commits.